# remove array element for a particular id

Tags: php, arrays

I am getting id like `$id=2` in a variable

like:
$count_id=$request->get('count_id');

and from a function i am getting a `array` like given below:
   like:$results=get_experiance();

```
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [A] => a
            [B] => b
            [C] => c
            [D] => d
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [A] => w
            [B] => s
            [C] => d
            [D] => a
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [A] => r
            [B] => e
            [C] => f
            [D] => v
        )
```

My question is that when i am getting the value in `$id=2` result should be like that :

```
[0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [A] => a
            [B] => b
            [C] => c
            [D] => d
        )
[1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [A] => r
            [B] => e
            [C] => f
            [D] => v
        )
```

Means i want to delete the record from the getting array based on id. How can i achieve this can anyone have simplest way ??

Comment: just unset that key like your array name is $arr and your key is 2 which is in $key then write unset($arr[$key])

Comment: Change the function to use the values of the `id` field as keys in the array it returns. After that, [it's easy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) to achieve your goal.

Comment: a simple foreach and an if should suffice, if found, just use unset

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=remove+array+of+objects++%5Bphp%5D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `array_filter`. You can also use `array_values` if you dont want to retain the existing keys.

```
$arr = your array
$toRemove = "2";
$result = array_filter($arr, function($o) use ($toRemove){
    return $toRemove != $o->id;
});

echo "<pre>";
print_r( $result );
echo "</pre>";
```

This will return:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [A] => a
            [B] => b
            [C] => c
            [D] => d
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
            [A] => r
            [B] => e
            [C] => f
            [D] => v
        )

)
```

---

If you dont want a new variable, you can just overide the array as

```
$arr = array_filter($arr, function($o) use ($toRemove){
    return $toRemove != $o->id;
});
```

Doc: [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php), [array_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

Answer (score -3):

You can do like:

unset($array[$id]);

`$array` is the main variable in which all elements of array contains

`$id` is the index

Comment: How is this answering the question?

Comment: Question is updated. At that time it was said that having a variable contains Index. Now updated that getting Id in a loop etc etc. Anyway my bad